# Creating branch folders in Github

Tags: git, github

In Azure devops when I create a branch in this manor:

```
git checkout -b feature/test1
```

it generates a folder hierarchy like below:

[image: Azure folder hierarchy]

Is there a way to achieve the above in Github?

Branching the same way on Github just adds it to the list of branches in the dropdown.

Comment: The difference is just how branches of certain names are displayed. The "folder hierarchy" is purely a display-time construct, in reality branch names have no inherent structure.